# Multiple Groovy jars in my war file

Tags: grails, groovy

I noticed that my Grails war has two Groovy jars in it: groovy-1.7-rc-2.jar and groovy-all-1.7.4.jar -- What could be causing this? I took a look at my plugin dependencies, and BuildConfig but didn't find anything...

Comment: Did you upgrade your grails version at all? Have you tried doing a **grails clean** and regenerating the war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking your classpath, and the libs included.